# MySQL search for Paul and Paul JD example?

Tags: mysql

Assuming that `Paul JD` and `Paul` are the same person, what is the correct MySQL statement for the search which will return both `Paul` and `Paul JD` either when searching for `Paul` or `Paul JD`?

My MySQL statement:

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM people WHERE name Like '%$h%' LIMIT 0, 5");
```

This statement does not return `Paul` when search for `Paul JD`.

Comment: And is Paulson also the same user and what about Paut or P?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't search for "Paul JD" - you should search for "Paul" which will find both "Paul" and "Paul JD".  Note that "Paul JD" is not a substring of "Paul" (but the converse is true).

Comment: -1 This solution puts the onus on the user. e.g. "Doctor, it hurts when I do this. Doctor answers: Don't do that!"

Comment: How would the program otherwise know to strip off the "JD"?  How do you know if it is or is not significant?  Only the user knows that.

Comment: It wouldn't strip anything, it would be smarter and split the arguments. Look at mine and Raj's answers. We both came up with the same idea.

Comment: Then you get hits on "JD Salinger" - probably not what is expected.  I think the user has to be in control of the search string and conscious of what "starts with" really means.  Not that taxing, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to break the incoming `PAUL JD` into two (delimited by space) and then search.

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM people WHERE name Like '%$FirstWord%' OR name Like '%$SecondWord%' LIMIT 0, 5");
```

But this is going to get tough pretty soon as you will want to match by **Paul**, **JD** or **PAUL JD**.

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM people WHERE name Like '%$FirstWord%' OR name Like '%$SecondWord% OR name Like '%$FirstWord%$SecondWord%' LIMIT 0, 5");
```

As it gets more complicated, you can create a Temporary Table, put the incoming strings into it, and use a JOIN and match.

Answer (score 0):

To enable the fuzzy-style of search you need to split your search arguments on white space and dynamically build a query string based on the number of parameters it contains.

So for the 'Paul JD' example your query string should look like:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM people WHERE name Like '%$h1%' OR name like'%$h2%' LIMIT 0, 5");
```

And when it executes it would look like:

```
SELECT * FROM people WHERE name Like '%Paul%' OR name like'%JD%' LIMIT 0, 5
```

To get really slick with your fuzzy searching you could implement the [Levenshtein Edit Distance algorithm](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#552) as a function. And use it to filter your results.